# RecyclerView inside HorizontalScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I am using a Recycler view inside a Horizontal Scroll View to display threaded comments like below:

> Comment1
>       Comment1Child1
>       Comment1Child2
>             Comment1Child2Child1
>       Comment1Child3 Comment2

etc.

I have done this with the following XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="2dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/commentRV"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
                    android:minWidth="200dp" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

You'll see I set a min width of 200dp so that the comments never get too small and the deeper down the thread they go the further off screen it will be pushed.

It is displaying perfectly but I am unable to scroll horizontally. I can see the scroll bars but I cannot scroll horizontally.

I have fiddled with disabling Touch and nestedScrollingEnabled in the RV but not sure what the real solution is. Nothing seems to work?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: You can simply use `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`. No need to use `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: @Piyush I am using a LayoutManager but I need the RV to be inside the HorizontalScroll otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 6):

Remove `HorizontalScrollView` you can give `LinearLayoutManager` with horizontal orientation like this

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
reclyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//recyclerView.setMinimumWidth(200); optional for width if u need
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps unfortunately? I am trying to make it scrollable. it is displaying correctly

Comment: Worked! `HorizontalScrollview` is not required. Setting `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` worked just fine. Thanks!